# Is there a way to browse the OS X App Store from iPad?

Tags: macos, ipad, mac-appstore

There are times that I'd like to browse the OS X App Store from my iPad - to get info for future reference.  But when I try, I get a message that I have to use a Mac.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Have you tried the Mac App Store Preview: https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/mac/id39?mt=12?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @jaume has mentioned, you can use the **Mac App Store Preview** on Apple's Website to browser apps from the Mac App Store. The same exists for iOS apps and is labeled as **iTunes Preview**.

As you will have already noticed, the search box on Apple's website is not very helpful when searching for Apps. The best alternative I can think of uses a google query. In the Google search box type:

[site:https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ "Mac App Store" MyKeyword](http://www.google.com/search?&q=site%3ahttps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/%20%22Mac%20App%20Store%22%20MyKeyword)

...which uses the URL:

```
http://www.google.com/search?&q=site:https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/%20%22Mac%20App%20Store%22%20
```

1. Copy and paste the URL
2. Add your keyword to the end (separate multiple keywords by `%20`)

Comment: Thanks to both @jaume and gentmatt.  From iMac, the itunes preview works -- I was going to say visa-versa in my question, so I'm peased to have this link as well.  I'm on the iMac now, but will use the ipad -> mac app version pretty soon.  Also, the search advice whould be helpful.